# How to get window start or end time from kafka topic corresponding to KSQL windowed table?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I want to get window start timestamp (here is 1530008520000) from kafka-console-consumer command.

It works with KSQL:

```
ksql> select * from DEV_MONITOR_RULE_2557_104782_233_2_TABLE;

1530008581051 | 2557 : Window{start=1530008520000 end=-} | 2557 | 2 | 1530008581051
```

But it does not work with kafka-console-consumer?

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper 10.12.0.157:2181 --topic DEV_MONITOR_RULE_2557_104782_233_2_TABLE

{"HITCOUNTS":2,"TENANTID":2557,"HITTIME":1530008581051}
```

How to print window start time (here is 1530008520000) from kafka-console-consumer?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?  Your SELECT query already includes this information, i.e. `1530008581051`?

Comment: How to print window start time (here is 1530008520000) from kafka-console-consumer instead of HITTIME 1530008581051?

Answer (score 1):

The window start time is reflected in the `ROWTIME` of the KSQL message, and in the timestamp of the Kafka message. This timestamp you can access using the standard APIs for working with Kafka messages.

AFAIK the `kafka-console-consumer` doesn't support showing timestamp. However something like [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/) does.

Here's some aggregated data in KSQL, with the `ROWTIME` showing the start of the window (and `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` being used to pretty-print it):

```
ksql> SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), ROWTIME, STARS, STAR_COUNT FROM RATINGS_AGG2;
2018-06-27 09:30:00 | 1530091800000 | 1 | 2
2018-06-27 09:30:00 | 1530091800000 | 4 | 6
2018-06-27 09:30:00 | 1530091800000 | 2 | 2
2018-06-27 09:30:00 | 1530091800000 | 3 | 3
```

Now the same topic in `kafkacat`:

```
$ kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -K: \
  -f '\nTimestamp: %T\t\tValue (%S bytes): %s' \
  -t RATINGS_AGG2

Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":1,"STARS":1}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":2,"STARS":1}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":3,"STARS":3}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":5,"STARS":1}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":6,"STARS":3}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":7,"STARS":1}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":7,"STARS":3}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":9,"STARS":1}
Timestamp: 1530091800000                Value (26 bytes): {"STAR_COUNT":9,"STARS":3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the kafka-console-consumer option `print.timestamp=true`?

```
$ kafka-console-consumer --property print.timestamp=true ...
```